# Pyspark with Zeppelin: distributing files to cluster nodes versus SparkContext.addFile()

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a library that I built that I want to make available to all nodes on a pyspark cluster (1.6.3). I run test programs on that spark cluster through Zeppelin (0.7.3).

The files I want are in a github repository. So I clone that repository onto all nodes of the cluster and made a script through pssh to update them all simultaneously. So the files exist at a set location on each node, and I want them accessible to each node.

I tried this

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/repo/folder/")

from module import function
return_rdd = function(arguments)
```

This yielded an error stack of:

```
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 439, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ImportError: No module named 'module'
```

I find this error unusual since it is prompted by the pickle call. The code appears to load a dataframe and partition it, but only fail when another function within module is called on the partitioned df converted to rdd. I'm not certain where and why the pickle call is involved here; the module pyscript should not need to be pickled since the modules in question should already be in sys.path on each node of the cluster.

On the other hand, I was able to get this working by

```
sc.addFile("/opt/repo/folder/module.py")
import sys
from pyspark import SparkFiles
sys.path.insert(0, SparkFiles.getRootDirectory())

from module import function
return_rdd = function(arguments)
```

Any idea why the first approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
sc.addFile("/opt/repo/folder/module.py")
import sys
from pyspark import SparkFiles
sys.path.insert(0, SparkFiles.getRootDirectory())

from module import function
return_rdd = function(arguments)
```

This is not working in cluster mode

Comment: You can use 4 spaces at the start of a line to mark a paragraf as a code block. This prettifies the formatting.